# Geolocation not working with PWA on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, geolocation, mobile-safari

I have a PWA that uses the Google Maps API and places an avatar on the map in accordance with javascript navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() method. 
It all works well when I open the PWA on `ANY browser` in `ANY laptop and Android/iPhone mobile phones`, but as soon as I published it in the Play and App Stores, it stopped working on iPhone (but still working on Android). The geolocation doesn’t work at all and doesn’t even ask permission to allow the app to use geolocation. I saw in forums everywhere and there’s a large tendency that says geolocation on installed web apps on iPhone doesn’t work.

First, in a previous PHP page I use the jQuery ajax() method:

```
        echo '
            <script>      
                var idcidade = '.$_POST['hitfcidadeid'].';
                $.ajax({
                    url:"geolocalizacao.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{hitfcidadeid: idcidade}, success:function(data) 
                    {}
                }); 
            </script>
        ';
```

In geolocalizacao.php I save the coordinates to two cookies:

```
        if (isset($_POST['hitfcidadeid']))
        {     
            echo '
                <script>       
                    function showLocation(position) {
                        document.cookie = "geolocationlat = " + position.coords.latitude;
                        document.cookie = "geolocationlong = " + position.coords.longitude;             
                    }
                    function errorHandler(err) {
                        document.cookie = "geolocationlat = '.$linha['CIlat'].'";
                        document.cookie = "geolocationlong = '.$linha['CIlong'].'";  
                    }
                    if(navigator.geolocation) {
                        var options = {timeout:60000};
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
                    } else {
                        document.cookie = "geolocationlat = '.$linha['CIlat'].'";
                        document.cookie = "geolocationlong = '.$linha['CIlong'].'"; 
                    }
                </script>       
            ';  
        }
```

Later on, on my map page:

```
        function getCookie(name)
        {
            var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
            var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
            return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
        } 
        if (getCookie("geolocationlat")==null || getCookie("geolocationlong")==null)
        {
            var lattemp = <?=$cidadelat2?>;
            var longtemp = <?=$cidadelong2?>; 
        }
        else
        {
            var lattemp = parseFloat(getCookie("geolocationlat"));
            var longtemp = parseFloat(getCookie("geolocationlong"));        
        }
```

`Result:`
`Laptop browser (chrome) – ok;`
`Android browser (chrome)  – ok;`
`iPhone browser (safari)  – ok;`
`Android web app – ok;`
`iPhone web app – not ok - returns null`

thanks in advance,

Comment: I also facing same issue,  Did you get solution ?

Comment: Not really, not the way I wanted at least. I had to do this https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/request-permission-core-location-ios-tutorial